# Query over ICollection of an entity in in linq to entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm asking my question in a simple way, Suppose these classes:

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int CategorytId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CategoryViewModel> CategoryViewModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class CategoryViewModel
    {
        public int CategorytId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

needless to say there would be a many to many relation between Product and Category, Now I just wanna to query all the products with all it's category as every product could has many category. to do that I've written this:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> GetAllProducts()
        {
            var _productContext = new ProductContext();

            var query = from product in _productContext.Products
                        join category in _productContext.Categories on product.ProductId equals category.CategorytId
                        select new ProductViewModel
                        {
                            ProductId = product.ProductId,
                            ProductName = product.ProductName,
                            CategoryViewModel = product.Categories.Select(c=>new CategoryViewModel
                            {
                                CategorytId = c.CategorytId,
                                CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
                            }).ToList()
                        };
            return query.ToList();
        }
```

but I receive this Error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List...

I know it's possible to query with navigation properties and Include method, but how can I do that with Linq?

Comment: remove .ToList from inner select

Comment: it's syntax error! you can't cast instance of an object to a list of another object

Comment: I think you and also me didn't notice about the ICollection<> in ProductViewModel, it was just because of that

Comment: .ToList() is only for IEnumerable not ICollection??

Comment: yes, I didn't notice about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ProductViewModel` class you need to change the `ICollection<...>` to `IEnumerable<...>` and then remove the inner `.ToList()` on the `CategoryViewModel` assignment

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
   ...
    public IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> CategoryViewModel { get; set; }
}

 CategoryViewModel = product.Categories.Select(c=>new CategoryViewModel
                            {
                                ...
                            })
```

Comment: please add some details why we cannot use ICollection<> / ToList().

Comment: @jony89 - `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.Collections.Generic.List...`, I do not know the technical reasons